Can an amazon pay button in principle be addd to another website?
Since shopify stopped supporting Amazon Pay altogether, I wonder if there might be a workaround to still have it on our site. After all its just a button with some javascript.
What or how would Amazon prevent us from integrating it on our site? Or can we in principle, have a button that redirects the user to a non shopifyshop and redirects them right into the amazon pay checkout?

Basically you can always build a custom integration. The payment process itself is really easy to implement. The main challenge will probably be to make sure, the amounts do match and to process the status of the "orders".
